# How do I get by the spinning spikes in Knight Fever?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

Sometimes I can get past them with no trouble, and other times I can't get anywhere.  How do I get through them consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a "magic bullet" of sorts that can make it a ton easier to get through this.  All you have to do, is move the camera up until it's looking down on your character like a top down game.  That's it!  It makes it infinitely easier to see the spikes coming for you and find the optimal path.  This made Knight Fever a ton easier for me, and I hope it's helpful for someone else.